# SQL - how to rename column being used on inner join

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I have created a view in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and I now want to join it to the correct spatial information.

I have created the query below

```
select * from v_postal_address_view pa
INNER JOIN SPATIAL_INFO sp ON sp.ECAD_ID = pa.BUILDING_ID
```

This runs fine as the ECAD_ID and BUILDING_ID are linked. However, I now want to save my results as a new view but cannot because the `v_postal_address_view` contains ECAD_ID already, therefore forbidding the `SPATIAL_INFO` tables ECAD_ID to be joined as the name is not unique.

How can I rename the ECAD_ID column in `spatial_info` during the inner join to the view??

Comment: Read the manual & introductions re join syntax & subqueries/subselects & table aliases (aka correlation names) & associated optional column renaming. This is an easily found faq. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW RESOLVE_AMBIGUOUS_NAMES AS
    SELECT T1.id AS id_1,
           T2.id AS id_2
      FROM TABLE_1 T1
     INNER
      JOIN TABLE_2 T2
        ON T1.fk = T2.pk
```

Comment: I want all my rows from table 1. It is the renaming of the column in table 2 that is causing issue

Comment: @ioquitteoo Not sure what you mean by "all rows from Table 1". This doesn't filter out any rows except for by consequence of an inner join. Most sql dialects will support CREATE VIEW RESOLVE_AMBIGUOUS_NAMES AS
    SELECT T1.*,
           T2.id AS id_2
      FROM TABLE_1 T1
     INNER
      JOIN TABLE_2 T2
        ON T1.fk = T2.pk